# How do xor a dataframe slice with the next num and insert the answer in column 'dr'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xor

Ok I have this data frame which you notice is names solve and I'm using a slice of 4

```
In [13147]: solve[::4]
Out[13147]: 
    rst  dr
0     1   0
4     3   0
8     7   0
12    5   0
16   14   0
20   12   0
24    4   0
28    4   0
32    4   0
36    3   0
40    3   0
44    5   0
48    5   0
52   13   0
56    3   0
60    1   0
```

What I want is to in column 'rst' xor 1 by 3 and get 2 (1^3=2). then I want to do 3^7 = 4, I want to put those in the corresponding spots in dr. so solve.loc[0:, ('dr')] = 2, and solve.loc[4:, ('dr')] = 4. My current method is tedious and not automatic, here is what I'm doing:

```
In [13150]: np.array(solve.loc[::4, ('rst')]) ^ np.array(solve.loc[4::4, ('rst')])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,) (15,)
```

which is resolved with:

```
In [13159]: wutwut = np.array(solve.loc[::4, ('rst')])[:15] ^ np.array(solve.loc[4::4, ('rst')])
Out[13159]: 
array([ 2,  4,  2, 11,  2,  8,  0,  0,  7,  0,  6,  0,  8, 14,  2],
      dtype=int8)
```

and then putting the values back into solve.loc['dr'] is an issue because I have to bust a length in manually like:

```
solve.loc[:56:4, ('dr')] = wutwut
```

see I have to manually set the length, is there a more automatic way

As you can see this is tedious and not practical because I'm working with different and changing lengths and I need a more automatic best practice cast for this. I'm looking for some suggestions and thanks in advance. Also I have more advanced use cases where is xor between columns so if anyone has strategies for that it will help me down the road as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets use loc for indexing and automatic value assignment

```
s = solve.loc[::4, 'rst']
solve.loc[s.index[:-1], 'dr'] = s[:-1].values ^ s[1:].values
```

---

```
    rst  dr
0     1   2
4     3   4
8     7   2
12    5  11
16   14   2
20   12   8
24    4   0
28    4   0
32    4   7
36    3   0
40    3   6
44    5   0
48    5   8
52   13  14
56    3   2
60    1   0
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped me  tremendously in automating this!